# Nothing happens when saving to local app directory? Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, directory, local-storage, file-storage

I'm picking an image from gallery, and then I should save it to the **App Local Directory**, But that directory is **never** created!

I'm using `image_picker` and `path_provider` libraries, and used no permission.

**Inside Press Button function:**

```
getImageIntoLocalFiles(ImageSource.gallery); //call getImage function
```

**The getImage function:**

```
Future getImageIntoLocalFiles(ImageSource imageSource) async {

    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

    // using your method of getting an image
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: imageSource);

    //debug
    print('${image?.path} ---image path'); //returns /data/user/0/com.ziad.TM.time_manager/cache/image_picker6496178102967914460.jpg

    // getting a directory path for saving
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;

    //debug
    if(image != null) print('$appDocPath ---local directory path'); //return /data/user/0/com.ziad.TM.time_manager/app_flutter

    // copy the file to a new path
    await image?.saveTo('$appDocPath/image1.png');
  }
```

I don't understand where is the problem as there is no errors and I can't find a documentation explaining this.

com.ziad.TM.time_manager is never actually created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to flutter's documentation

> `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` : On Android, this uses the
> *getDataDirectory* API on the context. Consider using
> `getExternalStorageDirectory` instead if data is intended to be **visible**
> to the user.

So, by changing `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` to `getExternalStorageDirectory()` the directory is created and the file is *successfully saved!!*

---

**I also found a way to create a new custom folder inside:**

```
String dirToBeCreated = "<New Folder Name>";

    if(baseDir != null) {
      String finalDir = join(baseDir.path, dirToBeCreated);
      var dir = Directory(finalDir);

      bool dirExists = await dir.exists();
      if (!dirExists) {
        dir.create(
            /*recursive=true*/); //pass recursive as true if directory is recursive
      }
```

and don't forget to pass `dir.path` to `saveTo()` parameter (a string path not a Directory)

Answer (score 0):

I solved just by using:

```
setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, relativePath, filename);
```

Instead of:

```
setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(relativePath, filename);
```

My relative path is:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "MyExternalStorageAppPath"
```

I also have in my manifest:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

To use Legacy storage management (Shared Storage) instead of new storage management (Scoped Storage) used from Android 10 and above.

Remember that by using "setDestinationInExternalFilesDir" files will be download to the external memory dedicated to your app, so: "external/Android/data/your_app_name/path_you_used_on_function".

Comment: I was saving into the app's specific directory, so you don't any permissions for that. Thanks!

Comment: @ZiadH.  No problem have a nice coding! :D

Answer (score 0):

To save the files, please follow below instructions.

find the correct path of the location you want to save by using [ext_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage) or [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider#-readme-tab-). You will need this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

on Android 10 you need this in your manifest

```
<application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

on Android 11 use this instead

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Remember to ask for them using [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

And to store file, please call below method

```
static Future saveInStorage(
      String fileName, File file, String extension) async {
    await _checkPermission();
    String _localPath = (await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))!;
    String filePath =
        _localPath + "/" + fileName.trim() + "_" + Uuid().v4() + extension;

    File fileDef = File(filePath);
    await fileDef.create(recursive: true);
    Uint8List bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
    await fileDef.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  }
```

Comment: Well, it seems like they have stopped supporting `ext_storage`. However, you don't any need permissions because you're saving in the app specific directory. I tried to mess more with the path_provider, and my problem was solved by using `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. I still don't know why it didn't work before but I will search some more. Thank a lot!